# Advice for editing question so problem more clearly stated

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Super User post: [Convert Windows 10 OEM install from Legacy to UEFI?](https://superuser.com/questions/1182819/convert-windows-10-oem-install-from-legacy-to-uefi)

My question was downvoted for allegedly being a duplicate. However, I had actually referenced the original post in my question as background, in order to ask a specific follow-up question (i.e. would an OEM license face issues that a retail license wouldn't).

After following the original question's solution, the following comment under my question ultimately turned out to be correct:

> The other response does not mention the "OEM environment" because no
>   such thing exists. Licensing is irrelevant. If the answer didn't work
>   with the vast majority of Windows installs it would be mentioned in
>   the answer.

Can I identify this comment as a solution to my OEM vs retail question? If not, should I edit my question to reflect that a helpful response was made? Or is there no need to make any further edits?

Comment: No need for further edits.  If it wasn't closed as a duplicate, you could add and accept an answer to formally document it and close the loop on the question.  You wondered whether another thread applied to your situation.  Rather than keep two separate threads, one just to say that the other applies, the two were linked and a clarification provided in a comment.  Anyone landing on your question will see the link to where the solutions are, and the clarification that they do apply.  So everything's good as is.

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice. The response to that other question came across as a little...blunt, so I wasn't sure if I was in the wrong or not.